# Pytorch: split a tensor by column

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

How can I split a tensor by column (axis = 1). For example

```
"""
input:              result:
tensor([[1, 1],     (tensor([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), 
        [2, 1],      tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]))
        [3, 2],  
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 3]])
"""
```

The solution I came out with is first transpose the input tensor, split it and then flatten each of the split tensor. However, is there a simpler and more effective way on doing this? Thank you

```
import torch
x = torch.LongTensor([[1,1],[2,1],[3,2],[1,2],[2,3],[3,3]])
x1, x2 = torch.split(x.T, 1)
x1 = torch.flatten(x1)
x2 = torch.flatten(x2)
x1, x2 # output
```

Comment: Why did use the tensorflow tag in this question?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Opps, didn't notice that. I just blindly selected the tags recommended for this question. BTW, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
x1 = x[:, 0]
x2 = x[:, 1]
# x1: (tensor([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), x2: tensor([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]))
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know that it will be that simple. TQVM

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark the answer as accepted ^^